# Getting distinct counts in DB::raw() after joining tables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm building an application in `Laravel` where I need to get the count from relational data, My code looks like:

```
$query->leftjoin('project_associate_company', 'companies.id', '=', 'project_associate_company.company_id')
    ->select('companies.*',DB::raw('count(DISTINCT project_associate_company.project_id) as project_count'))
    ->groupBy('companies.id')
    ->orderBy('project_count',  $filter['order']);
```

I'm joining the tables then trying to get the values, I know I can use `withCount()` or can have `count()` function but I need to have count while I can use `select()` after joining the tables.

Thanks.

Comment: what result are you getting running this code? show full block of code please.

Comment: @HafezDivandari I'm getting total count, not able to get unique counts respective to project_id.

Comment: How about grouping also by project_id?

Comment: @Kiafar can you share some example?